# write between two characters in C

Tags: c

I have a very big text file and I am writing code that tries to find all '' (two single quotation marks in a row) and then write a number between these two single quotation marks. Can I do this in C? I am using a pointer to find the '' . Thank you.

```
letter1 = fgetc(fptr);
if(letter1=="'"){
  fseek(fptr, 1, SEEK_CUR); 
  letter2=fgetc(fptr);
  if(letter=="'"){

  }
}
else{
  fseek(fptr, 1, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're having?

Comment: the problem is the how to add a number between ' '. (for example ' ' ->'434')

Comment: @user3121023 That's too much work for this?

Answer (score 1):

Most programs (I've come across) write out a new file and replace the old one with it.
You can do it in place, but you're going to have to move the bytes after where you want to insert to prevent overwriting.
The `mmap`, `mremap` functions might help you turn it into a `memmove` operation if you're on a POSIX system.